# Cryptogram vector not working

Tags: java, vector, cryptography

[Cryptogram problem descirption photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7cHC.png)   So the point of this assignment is to write 2 vectors. One vector will hold a constant vector of string objects. Then we are supposed to copy the elements of this 1'st vector into a 2'nd vector. The 2'nd vector is supposed to have  an asterisk in place of all the letters. Afterwards, the user is allowed to type in a letter they want to replace, with a letter of their choice, and then we are supposed to  continually display what the first constant vector, with the 2'nd vector (which is changed by the user is input), while the rest of the word is in  asterisks. My problem is, every time I think I replace the elements the user asks for, and reprint it, it always gives me the same vector with "*". Anyone see what the problem can be? Any tips would be useful as well. (I am still a begginer to Java and vectors). Here is also what the assignment asks:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Cryptogram {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = new String("X AQC'M YCQO OKJM BQG OJCM   
    DGM X SJC'M WXZP XM JCB TQVP");
    final Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
        vec.add(i, Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
    }
    Vector<String> vec2 = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(vec.elementAt(i));
        vec2.add(i, vec.elementAt(i));
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    Collections.fill(vec2,"*");
    vec2.set(1, " ");
    vec2.set(5, "'");
    vec2.set(7, " ");
    vec2.set(12, " ");
    vec2.set(17, " ");
    vec2.set(21, " ");
    vec2.set(26, " ");
    vec2.set(30, " ");
    vec2.set(32, " ");
    vec2.set(36, "'");
    vec2.set(38, " ");
    vec2.set(43, " ");
    vec2.set(46, " ");
    vec2.set(50, " ");
    for(int i=0; i<vec2.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(vec2.elementAt(i));
    }
    boolean flag = true;
    String letter_replace;
    String new_letter;
    System.out.print("\n \n");
    while(flag){
        System.out.print("Replace a letter from encoded message: ");
        letter_replace = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Replace with which letter (A-Z,*): ");
        new_letter = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<vec2.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(vec.elementAt(i));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<vec2.size(); i++){
            if(vec2.elementAt(i)==letter_replace){
                vec2.setElementAt(new_letter, i);
            }
            System.out.print(vec2.elementAt(i));
        }
        System.out.print("\n \n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if(vec2.elementAt(i)==letter_replace)

when comparing objects, you should always use .equals because == compares if the references are equal rather than the objects

Comment: I did that, but it is still giving me an error because it is still displaying vec2 as a line of asterisks. Is there anything you can tlel me to help?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you were searching in vec2 (the asterik vector), while you should have been searching in vec (the encoded message)

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Cryptogram {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = new String("X AQC'M YCQO OKJM BQG OJCM DGM X SJC'M WXZP XM JCB TQVP");
    final Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
        vec.add(i, Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
    }
    Vector<String> vec2 = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(vec.elementAt(i));
        vec2.add(i, vec.elementAt(i));
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    Collections.fill(vec2,"*");
    vec2.set(1, " ");
    vec2.set(5, "'");
    vec2.set(7, " ");
    vec2.set(12, " ");
    vec2.set(17, " ");
    vec2.set(21, " ");
    vec2.set(26, " ");
    vec2.set(30, " ");
    vec2.set(32, " ");
    vec2.set(36, "'");
    vec2.set(38, " ");
    vec2.set(43, " ");
    vec2.set(46, " ");
    vec2.set(50, " ");
    for(int i=0; i<vec2.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(vec2.elementAt(i));
    }
    boolean flag = true;
    String letter_replace;
    String new_letter;
    System.out.print("\n \n");
    while(flag){
        System.out.print("Replace a letter from encoded message: ");
        letter_replace = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Replace with which letter (A-Z,*): ");
        new_letter = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<vec2.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(vec.elementAt(i));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
            if(vec.elementAt(i).equals(letter_replace)){
                vec2.setElementAt(new_letter, i);
            }
            System.out.print(vec2.elementAt(i));
        }
        System.out.print("\n \n");
    }
}
}
```